# axios retry request but data-object isn't sent again

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a react native app and a nodejs backend. I'm using refresh and access tokens for authentication. My RN code looks like this (simplified):

```
 const onRequest = (config) => {
    console.log('data before request', config.data);
    
    config.headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.current}`,
      'phosphor-device-id': `${deviceId}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

    return config;
  };

  const onRequestError = (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  };

  const onResponse = (response) => {
    return response;
  };

  const onResponseError = async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !oConfig._retry) {
      oConfig._retry = true;
      return refreshAccessToken().then((token) => {
        accessToken.current = token;
        apiCall.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        oConfig.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        return apiCall.request(oConfig);
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          accessToken.current = null;
          setAuth(false);
          Promise.reject(error);
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }

  apiCall.interceptors.request.use(onRequest, onRequestError);

  apiCall.interceptors.response.use(onResponse, onResponseError);
```

In my nodejs code, I have middleware to check for incoming requests. It looks like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`${req.method}: ${req.url}`);

  if (Object.keys(req.query).length > 0) {
    console.log('query params', req.query);
  }

  if (Object.keys(req.body).length > 0) {
    console.log('body params', req.body);
  }

  next();
});
```

When the user submits an item with an expired access token, the response is "catched" by the axios response interceptor, and a new access token is generated and send back to the user. **This works.** Also, with `return apiCall.request(oConfig);`, the original request is retried. **This does not work.**

The first time , I get some logs about the request in my server console about the received req.body (thanks to the middleware). In my react native console, I see this body-object also (thanks to `console.log('date before request', config.data);` So when the request is retried, the full original body/data-object is send again to the server. **But the second time, the req.body-object on the server (or what the server receives) is empty**. I don't get any output in my node.js-middleware about the req.body-object, and my controller fails because it needs this content.

This only happens with POST requests (and req.body). When a "refresh-access-token" happens with a GET-request, the req.query-object is still complete in the second try.

What can possibly be wrong with this?

Edit: ofc I'm using `express.json()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using error.config instead of oConfig

```
  const onResponseError = async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401 && ! error.config._retry) {
      error.config._retry = true;
      return refreshAccessToken().then((token) => {
        accessToken.current = token;
        apiCall.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        error.config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        return apiCall.request(error.config);
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          accessToken.current = null;
          setAuth(false);
          Promise.reject(error);
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
```